# How to prove convergence of sequence with $\epsilon$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

If we have sequence $(\frac{4^{n}+1}{5^{n}})_{n\in \mathbb{N_{0}}}$, it is easy to calculate limit of it:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} = \frac{4^{n}+1}{5^{n}}=\frac{(\frac{4}{5})^{n}+\frac{1}{5^{n}}}{1}=\frac{0+0}{1}=0$

But how can i prove it with $\epsilon$, if we know:

$(\forall \epsilon>0)(\exists N\in\mathbb{N}) (\forall n \geq N): \left|  a_{n}-a\right|< \epsilon$ ?

We should start with $ \left| \frac{4^{n}+1}{5^{n}}-0 \right|=\left| \frac{4^{n}+1}{5^{n}} \right|=$, how should i continue this proof?

Comment: You could probably use the triangle equality, for example $|\frac{4^n+1}{5^n}| \le |\frac{4^n}{5^n}|+|\frac{1}{5^n}|$.

Comment: You could estimate the numerator, for example, as $4^n+1<2\cdot4^n.$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ implies 
$$
\frac{4^{n}+1}{5^{n}} = (\frac{4}{5})^{n} + (\frac{1}{5})^{n}.
$$
Let $\varepsilon > 0$.
Note that
$(4/5)^{n} < \varepsilon/2$ if $n\log(4/5) < \log (\varepsilon/2)$ with $\log(4/5) < 0$, so $n > \log(\varepsilon/2)/|\log(4/5)|$ implies $(4/5)^{n} < \varepsilon/2$.
Note that likewise $n > \log(\varepsilon/2)/|\log(1/5)|$ implies $(1/5)^{n} < \varepsilon/2$.
Note that if $n >$ the greater one of two obtained numbers, then we make it.